# bool operator in for Timestamp in Series does not work

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

For some reason I cannot check if a date is in a Pandas Series.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
ts = pd.Series(['2011-01-01','02-02-2011'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
d = np.datetime64(pd.Timestamp('02-02-2011'))
```

Now...

```
In [5]: d == ts[1]
Out[5]: True

In [6]: d in ts
Out[6]: False
```

Can someone explain me why `d in ts` does not work?

TIA,

Olivier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you use 
`value in obj`, python tries to pass value to `__contains__` built-in function of obj

try to check the type of ts:

```
In [1]: type(ts)
Out[1]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

if you see `pandas.core.series.Series`, you will find the definition of `__contains__` as below:

```
def __contains__(self, key):
    return key in self.index
```

So, try this:

```
In [2]: 0 in ts
Out[2]: True
In [3]: 1 in ts
Out[3]: True
```

It tries to check whether given key is in it's index or not, not checking in it's values

```
In [4]: d in ts.values
Out[4]: True
```

Comment: Ok it makes it but then, why it is not consistent? If I use integer: `ts = pd.Series([1,2,3])` then `2 in ts` gives `True`

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations (why it solve the issue, where was the mistake, etc...)

Comment: hope I could explain as you asked in edition to my previous answer :)

Comment: The long explanation is clear, thanks :-) My example with `ts = pd.Series([1,2,3])` was just back luck, index having same values than values.